# How can I set cookie value in one page and read it from another page in a asp.net website

Tags: c#, asp.net, cookies

This is my code in Login.aspx

```
protected void LoginButton_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    HttpCookie loginCookie1 = new HttpCookie("loginCookie");
    Response.Cookies["loginCookie1"].Value = LoginUser.UserName;
    Response.Cookies.Add(loginCookie1);
}
```

And this is in shop.aspx

```
protected void btnAddCart_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{ 
     HttpCookie myCookie = new HttpCookie(dvProduct.DataKey.Value.ToString());
     myCookie["Category"] = dvProduct.DataKey["Category"].ToString();
     myCookie["Product"] = dvProduct.DataKey["Product"].ToString();
     myCookie["Quantity"] = txtQuantity.Text;
     myCookie["Price"] = dvProduct.DataKey["Price"].ToString();
     myCookie.Expires = DateTime.Now.AddDays(1d);
     Response.Cookies.Add(myCookie);
     Response.Redirect("ViewCart.aspx", true);
}
```

I want to read the value of username from cookie(value set in login.aspx

Comment: Small correction--> I want to read the value of username from cookie(value set in login.aspx) from shop.aspx page

Comment: As a note, you shouldn't store the username in a cookie; this is a security vulnerability.  It's very easy to change the value of a cookie from the client, and then all they need to do is guess the name of an administrator to get full access to your system.  Instead, associate the user with a guid and store the guid in the cookie.  On the return trip, look up the information stored with the guid on the server.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

you basically need to request the cookie it does not really matter on what page you are 
here is an explanation about cookies

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms178194.aspx

```
HttpCookie aCookie = Request.Cookies["loginCookie"];
string username = Server.HtmlEncode(aCookie.Value);
```

Comment: @techblog : remember to upvote the answers you think are good. That gives us all a warm fuzzy feeling :P .. And if this answer was the resolution to your question then accept it.. I like this +1.

Answer (score 5):

Your code that sets loginCookie looks strange:

```
HttpCookie loginCookie1 = new HttpCookie("loginCookie"); 
Response.Cookies["loginCookie1"].Value = LoginUser.UserName; // <--- strange!!!!
Response.Cookies.Add(loginCookie1);
```

Most likely your cookie does not get send  to browser - check with HTTP debugger like [Fiddler](http://www.fiddler2.com).

Comment: >I am retrieving the username from the Login control of asp.net. LoginUser is the ID of the Login control. Here I checked if it is retrieving the username, it is retrieving it fine. I am just having thr trouble reading it.

Comment: Please post what cookie header is actuallly send to browser by "login.aspx" and from browser back in "shop.aspx" page.

Comment: >Hi, I got the solution. Below code solved the problem.
    HttpCookie aCookie = Request.Cookies["loginCookie1"];
    string username = Server.HtmlEncode(aCookie.Value);

>Thanks.

Comment: Good to hear. It is a way too I guess... also fixing strange code on login page to set cookie with name you expcect is probably more appropriate.

Answer (score 1):

This should do it:

```
var userName = Request.Cookies["loginCookie"].Value;
```

Comment: >I am getting this error with the above code <br>{"Object reference not set to an instance of an object."}

Comment: Its because you can't get the value of a null object.